# How to develop Asp.Net application for Ubuntu using vs 2015

Tags: mono, asp.net5

I am a windows user and I have a requirement to develop an asp.net application which should run on both windows and Ubuntu servers.

I tried this installing Ubuntu on VM workstation player and downloading Mono, DNX, DNVM and visual studio code. But this is very hard for me since I am  familiar with neither Ubuntu nor VS Code.

Is there any method to develop cross platform applications using VS 2015 on windows environment and build packages for other platforms such as Linux, OS X ?

Moreover I would like to know which web server is the most suitable for run .Net application on Ubuntu.

Comment: You should first upgrade to .NET Core RC2. DNX/DNVM are dead. So far, the tooling is still in development (SDK in Preview 1, VS vNext is in Preview too). So if you really want to jump on board right now, VS Code is the only option on Ubuntu. For what servers should be used, https://docs.asp.net already gives you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this depending on your needs and the context. It is possible to develop using VS2015 on Windows and to deploy to Apache 2 with mod_mono (best option imho) or possibly to Mono XSP4 (this web server has some limitations) or if you're game for a challenge you could use kestrel and dnx. You should also be able to open and continue developing your existing VS2015 project on Linux using MonoDevelop, which may make your life easier for debugging. In either scenario I would recommend that you give yourself the time and opportunity to familiarise with Apache, Linux etc. as you go. Happy to help further but I'm not sure quite what your context is...